# Django How to pass instance to view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I can't find out how to do this, I have a list view, that when you click on one of the list objects, it takes you to an update page, but I can't work out how you pass the instance so to it so that and data posted goes to that instance on the database. CBV do this automatically in a hidden black box way, and I can't see how it is done for a function based view.

Model

```
class Project(models.Model):
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=64)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Form

```
class ProjectUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Update
        fields = [
            'project',
            'category',
            'update'
        ]
```

View

```
def project_update_view(request, slug):
    obj = Project.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form = ProjectUpdateForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    context = {
        "form": form,
        "object": obj
    }
    return render(request, 'project_portal/project_update.html', context)
```

url:

```
path('<slug:slug>/update/', project_update_view, name='project-update'),
```

So I want to be able to do away with the 'project' field in the Form because the user is already looking at that instance he shouldn't have to then pick it in the form.

Comment: " CBV do this automatically in a hidden black box way ". How is this possible?? I have CBV that's needs to use it but I don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the project in the field, and set in in the view, like:

```
class ProjectUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Update
        fields = [
            # 'project',
            'category',
            'update'
        ]
```

In the view, you can then set the `project` attribute of the instance manually:

```
def project_update_view(request, slug):
    obj = Project.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectUpdateForm(request.POST)
        form.instance.project = obj
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('success-url')
    else:
        form = ProjectUpdateForm()
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "object": obj
    }
    return render(request, 'project_portal/project_update.html', context)
```

Some extra notes:

1. do *not* use `request.POST or None`, since a POST request can be valid and have no POST parameters;
2. in case the POST is successful, you should implement a [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: @Wilem Van Onsem, thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for!